# View element dissappears on giving flex : 1

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is my element, i want my element to take the whole screen but instead the element disappears, don't know why this is happening! can anyone help?

```
    <View style={ styles.container }
    >



    </View>
```

heres my style

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#000',
    },
});
```

Comment: Is there any another view above it?

Comment: No thats the parent element

Comment: Please, add text and then check it. Can you attach the screenshot to this question?

Comment: I had added text inside the parent element, but still it wont show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flex fits in the width but u should be required to add height, for to cover the whole screen

```
 container:{
        flex: 1,
        height: "100vh",
        backgroundColor: '#000',
    },
```

it has 0 height at this moment. so its not visible